# Navigation class not found

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect to my phpmyadmin using xampp butit gives me some unknown error

I tried searching google but none pointed particularly to my problem

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
> 'PhpMyAdmin\Navigation\NavigationTree' not found in
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Navigation\Navigation.php:52 
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Header.php(440): PhpMyAdmin\Navigation\Navigation->getDisplay()
> #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(266): PhpMyAdmin\Header->getDisplay()
> #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(279): PhpMyAdmin\Response->_getDisplay()
> #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(438): PhpMyAdmin\Response->_htmlResponse()
> #4 [internal function]: PhpMyAdmin\Response->response()
> #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Navigation\Navigation.php on lin
> ```

Comment: Sounds like the broken XAMPP installation check the namespace and make a sure file with a specific class exist. Try reinstalling XAMPP

Comment: I will surely try but is there any specific reason behind this because i didn't do anything new to my xampp

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing XAMPP did the trick